# Setting multiple conditions using conditional AND/OR Operators in aura:if attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

I had tried this on my own, but couldn't achieve the functionality of having multiple conditions checked using conditional 'OR' operator of an aura:if attribute.

I tried to render a div only when the value of a Text type aura attribute is equal to particular Text Strings. But, it didn't worked for me.

My code is as below :

```
<aura:attribute name="Text1" type="String"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!OR(v.Text1=='Hello',v.Text1=='Bye')}">
<div>
ABCD
</div>
</aura:if>
```

I tried other combinations as well, like ;

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.Text1 =='Hello' || !v.Text1 =='Bye'}">
</aura:if>
```

But that also didn't worked.
Do someone has any idea about how to make it work?

Comment: Your first attempt should work (with `or(exp1,exp2)` ) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm Are you sure `Text1` is getting the expected value?

Comment: Yes @Ranga, the expected value was received, but the content under aura:if was not displayed.

Comment: is this still an issue it is working for me try upgrading your lightning component version. What I noticed the maximum number of condition supported is 1 like or( condition 1 , condition 2)  is supported but or(condition 1, condition 2 , condition 3, condition 4) never works

Answer (score 4):

Try this:-

```
<aura:attribute name="Text1" type="String"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(v.Text1=='Hello',v.Text1=='Bye')}">
       <div>
         ABCD
       </div>
</aura:if>
```

It will work. What you were doing wrong is your **T** is small in **isTrue** as it is case sensitive and also Hello and bye should be in **single quotes** when you are comparing an attribute to a string:

```
<aura:if istrue="{!OR(v.Text1=="Hello",v.Text1=="Bye")}">
```

change it to

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(v.Text1=='Hello',v.Text1=='Bye')}">
```

Comment: That is not the case, Sanket, I tried what you had suggested, its just that while posting the question, I didn't care about the syntax. What you have suggested is what I had tried already.

Comment: Are you setting the value of your attribute Text1 in client side controller with the value you mentioned in your code?

Comment: Yes, the javascript controller is the one which is setting the values into these attriubutes.